# How to build AOSP app without building all of Android?

Tags: android, build, android-source

I've synced the entire Android repo, and set up a build environment per the instructions here:
https://source.android.com/source/building

The build instructions seem to be assuming that you want to build the entire Android platform. I'm really interested in building a specific AOSP app, like contacts, SMS, camera, etc. I've seen mirrors of the stock app's code on GitHub, but there doesn't seem to be any build instructions within those, for example:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar

Is there a build guide for doing this? Am I stuck downloading, modifying, building this huge (100+GB) code set?

Comment: "Am I stuck downloading, modifying, building this huge (100+GB) code set?" -- in general, yes. Those apps are not designed to be built in isolation from the rest of the firmware.

Comment: Understood, I get that there's most likely some dependencies, etc, that will tie it into the entire ROM codebase. But once I start making customizations, I'd like to be able to output an APK package, and I'm not sure that's accomplished in the AOSP make process, is it?

Per the build instructions, it seems that it'll generate an entire ROM package ready to go into an emulator or device.

Comment: Correct, though that ROM package will contain APKs for the apps. However, please bear in mind that those APKs cannot be installed on devices that already have those packages, and those APKs may not be able to run on arbitrary devices anyway (as those apps tend to use non-SDK classes and methods that may not exist on ROMs other than the one that you are building).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as you have '*mm*' to build a certain target, you can also use '*mma*' to build that target with its dependencies. For example:

```
$ mma Settings -j16
```

This will scan the project for the dependencies of the Settings app, and will afterward build the dependencies first before commencing the build of the Settings app.

Comment: I need to compile framework/minikin from AOSP for NDK use, any instruction?

Answer (score 0):

here are compile and module-based compilation commands:

```
lunch:   lunch <product_name>-<build_variant>
tapas:   tapas [<App1> <App2> ...] [arm|x86|mips|armv5] [eng|userdebug|user]
croot:   Changes directory to the top of the tree.
m:       Makes from the top of the tree.
mm:      Builds all of the modules in the current directory, but not their dependencies.
mmm:     Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, but not their dependencies.
        To limit the modules being built use the syntax: mmm dir/:target1,target2
mma:     Builds all of the modules in the current directory, and their dependencies.
mmma:    Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, and their dependencies.
cgrep:   Greps on all local C/C++ files.
jgrep:   Greps on all local Java files.
resgrep: Greps on all local res/*.xml files.
godir:   Go to the directory containing a file.
```

you can look here for other and more build commands : https://source.android.com/setup/build/building
and here :https://elinux.org/Android_Build_System
And check "build/envsetup.sh" file's comments to see full list.